# String theory and the SM spectrum

Tags: string-theory, mass, elementary-particles, string-theory-landscape

Long ago, I realized this: (super)string theory can NOT give a well-defined/unique prediction of why the electron (muon, tau) or the neutrino (any flavor) masses have the masses we measure. String theory can NOT give a concrete prediction of any SM particle mass (even resonances like the Higgs and other particles). The question is: Is this lack of predictive ability of the mass of the SM "elementary particles" a hint that string theory in its current status is not complete or wrong? Or perhaps even better:

**Even when string theory provides a framework in which you can accomodate every Standard Model field, and hence, a priori you can have the SM spectrum, we have not a string theory explanation of the values of the masses and charges. Should a explicit derivation of particle properties like (rest) masses and (bare) charges (like the electron charge value) be "predicted" and "derived" in a more fundamental version of the theory?**

Comment: We already know that string theory is incomplete as it's currently formulated.  We don't need "hints".

Comment: It could also be wrong as we understand it. It could be the case that the final theory is NOT string theory after all...

Comment: In fact, what I asked is that the lack of predictive power to determined some specific particle properties could be related to the "wrongness" in the theory...

Comment: Why do you even believe that mass ratios can be derived from first principles? Kepler thought for a while the ratios of the distances of the planets could be derived from first principles. That was wrong, too.

Comment: GUTs and some seesaw models in which there are some "symmetries" provide some ratios. Dimensionless "parameters", like alpha, should be derived from "fundamental constants", like the Rydberg constant. Of course, I agree with you: it is a prejudice (in Feynman's sense). I am not the one who told that by the first time ;).

Comment: This is too broad and much too opinion based, vote to close.

Comment: Dilaton, is it not the compactification of any string theory "too broad" and "too much" opinion based as well?

Comment: Ok, I could have voted to close as not a real question too, since I strongly doubt that you are really interested in hearing what experts have to say in the form of an answer or that you are ready to think about any answers you get seriously (apart from potentially incoming trolling answers that support your dismissive point of view). I rather suspect that by this post you just wanted to state your personal negative opinion about string theory on this site and that's it ;-)

Comment: NO, I was not. Indeed, I like p-adic string theory! Of course, those "models" like Arefeva works in tachyon condensation and cosmological models are not "mainstream", but I was and I AM interested in what "the most expert" in this theory can say. I am also a close follower of ncategory lab (by Urs, Baez and others), so I keep in touch with "ideas" from pure math too :). But you are right, I wanted to be controversial a little bit. But please,note that even when I am not a big fan of strings NOW (I was years ago), I am not opposed to some of its ideas.

Comment: Yeah, so this came out maybe a bit more controversial than intended? It really astonished me (was wondering what picks you), since I like your interesting contributions to Physics SE a lot and I appreciate among other things a nice answer you once have given to me :-)

Comment: You have also very interesting additions in Lubos Motl blog , Mr. Dilaton ;). Sometimes I use "cyberpsychology" ;). Well, I have been asked to edit this, how could I improve it?Any idea?

Comment: @riemannium The problem is that you are looking to have a discussion about a question which doesn't really have clear answers.  That's not what StackExchange is for.  Get a blog.

Comment: I do have a blog... However, this question in interesting in its own. HOw is string theory aiming to "derive" masses from v.e.v. of some (likely) higher dimensional fundamental theory if it can barely explain the value of the electron mass? I think this is a relevant question even for experts. Of course, some people believe it doesn't. But if we were able to "understand" the spectrum of the hydrogen atom or more complex atoms, why can not understand the Standard Model spectrum? String theory does not offer (as far as I know) a good answer to it. Of course, even the SM spectrum is "mysterious".

Comment: @riemannium maybe the question about the fundamental origin of mass generally and the issue concerning predictions of the mass the SM particles should better be separated in two questions? Concerning the second one as I understand things the problem is that it is very difficult to narrow the landscape down by physical and mathematical methods. The (inner working of) the theory has to be understood better to achieve this, and this is difficult and ongoing research. Concerning the mass issue I do not quite understand what you mean, should there be something more fundamental than higgsing?

Comment: Yes, the Higgs field only "shifts" the issue. As far as I can undertand it now. I mean, the issue of mass in theories with "fundamental scalars" is shifted to the question of why the v.e.v. is X and not Y. It is analogue to the ADD scenario to see why Gravity is weaker: the size of the the Xdimension. Well, I agree in that this question is "hard", but the energy spectrum should be "derived"...

Comment: @riemannium yeah, finally predicting the SM particles as low energy spectrum by better understanding the theory and narrowing down the landscape by new insights, is what I'd think is the nice thing to try, conversely to just invoking the anthropic principle or reasoning which I jokingly consider to be a copout to do thing right ... :-P

Comment: The anthropic principle (even when I have read how Weinberg "used" it in his celebrated review of the cosmological problem) is not a principle at all. It is just like the god hypothesis. Anthropic reasons arise when there is no better explanation to some problem.

Comment: @riemannium yep, that is why I dont like the anthropic reasoning in the context of such questios as you ask here for example, to me it looks like giving up or throwing in the towel concerning the problem at hand ...

Comment: @riemannium this just came to my mind: Maybe the question would look better and less controversial, if you would leave the hints to possible answers and discussion issues out. Some of these 7 points contain issues that could be asked in separate questions if they are not already asked on the site.

Comment: @riemannium I think that why questions are not really answered by physics mathematical models, which is what string theory will be when/if finalized. The answers physics models give are of HOW. How from the axioms/postulates of the theoretical model the experimental data are described and new data predicted successfully. All the why questions are actually nested how answers that eventually hit the axioms/postulates. In a mathematical theory the answer would be because I chose the axioms. In a mathematical model of physics the answer is "because I fit the data by these axioms and predict new".

Comment: continued: the why is on par with metaphysical questions: why  do I exist? the only answer is "because". Now there exist an extension of the platonists/pythagoreans who believed that the universe was the music of the spheres, that everything was described by the music of the spheres. One could postulate the everything is described by a mathematical formula, from DNA to rocks, planets, etc... everything is an eigenvalue of a preexisting mathematical formulation, a mathematical God so to say. In such a pov the masses would come out of the formulae, but it is metaphysics.

Answer (score 11):

None of our known theories of physics makes any predictions before specifying a *model* in the theory.

Think about it: There are many, many choices made to pick the standard model of particle physics out of the huge space of possible local QFTs. Think about how vast that space is, the "landscape of QFT": you can write down pretty much any local Lagrangian that is quantum anomaly free and get a QFT. Nothing in general QFT "predicts" that the world is described by Yang-Mills theory coupled to fermions with the gauge group and the coupling constants seen in the standard model of particle physics. These are a huge number of choices we humans make to fit QFT parameters. Only once all these choices are made, does the standard model start to predict anything.

That why it's called the standard *model* and not the standard *theory*! The standard theory is QFT, but that alone predicts nothing.

Same for the standard model of cosmology. Nothing in Einstein gravity *predicts* that the universe is modeled on large scales by an FRW model with positive cosmological constant. The back and forth with the assumptions made here is legendary (Einstein's "biggest blunder" in model building is now our Nobel worthy insight. Nothing predicted it.) Only after the FRW model is chosen, only after dark matter content is adjusted to fit observations, only then does Einstein gravity start to make predictions in cosmology. The "landscape of Einstein gravity" is huge and vast: think about all the possible solutions to Einstein's equations. There are not just 10^500 of them. It's certainly not a finite set, it's a hugely infinite-*dimensional* space.

One needs to remember this before getting worked up about the alleged lack of predictivity of string theory.

For in string theory it's the same: of course the theory itself doesn't predict anything. Just as QFT and Einstein gravity by themselves predict nothing. In each case one first needs to fix a model and *then* the theory make predictions about the remaining parameters.

The irony of this is: the constraints on model building in string theory are much stronger than in QFT. Not every model in QFT lifts to a model in string theory (the "Swampland" doesn't sit in the "Landscape"). On the other hand, string theory models generically contain Einstein-Yang-Mills theory. At least that. In QFT you can write down weird theories that have nothing to do with the real world. Like phi^4 theory. In string theory you cannot, since its much more constrained. String theory predicts that the world is not described by phi^4 theory. QFT cannot predict that. For instance.

So string theory is clearly *more* predictive than QFT! Think about it. In string theory we have a chance of arguing that there may be a *finite* number of models -- even if it is a large finite number such as 10^500. This is nothing against the hugely vastly infinite-*dimensional* space of choices of writing down local QFTs.

String theory, just as QFT and just as Einstein gravity, starts making predictions as soon as you specify a model. And that's precisely what string phenomenologist's do. They build models (or approximations to them, because in string theory its harder, since it is more constrained) and check against the known observational constraints. Then they refine their models. This process keeps going on check out the commented links at

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+phenomenology

Also check out the pertinent paragraphs at

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+theory+FAQ

And think about. Don't just repeat the "Oh my, oh my, string theory makes no predictions." that you hear in the blogosphere. Before you repeat this, think about what it means for physical theories to make predictions, how QFT makes predictions only once we choose the standard model.

Comment: Dear Urs, I have not said that String Theory does not make any predictions. In fact, the problem is quite the contrary. It does make too many (unseen) predictions. I have studied the theory during my master in Theoretical Physics. The fact that today I am not a big fan of string theory it does not mean I do not study it or that I can critize it. Constructive criticism is basic for the improvement of theories or models. Do you agree? I am only pointing out that string theory has a problem there, not that I can be more or less a stringer myself...

Comment: This is exactly the nice reasonable answer such a way to confrontationally formulated question needs. How I'd like to upvote this a second or even third time ... !

Comment: It's not about being a "fan" or a "stringer". It's about logical reasoning in science. String theory might be wrong, but not because it has more than one vacuum and not because it doesn't uniquely predict the observed elementary mass spectrum. That's not a logically sensible criticism. You might as well complain that it doesn't predict your telephone number. I would like to see people concentrate and have decent arguments about string theory. Feel free to try to trash it, that's what science is about, but know some good reasons.

Comment: OT sociological comment: I guess a lot of this reaction stems from how string theory was hyped up (and I believe some may still be hold outs for the idea that some physical principle picks out a unique solution? That's how I would lean if I was doing string theory.). I remember as a kid being incredibly excited by string theory as the final theory which explains everything! The reality that string theory is just like everything that came before it is sinking in and some people get jaded. Others grin and bear it. And others (myself) move to more "practical" things (applied QFT within the SM).

Comment: You could argue that these were irrational hopes to begin with and no one should have taken them so seriously. I would agree. Anyway, your answer is very good so +1. It also relates to my question here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70836/what-is-the-relationship-between-string-theory-and-quantum-field-theory

Comment: @MichaelBrown : I don't think that [string phenomenology](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2795) is not "practical".

Comment: @Michael Brown, yes, I think back in the 20th century many hopes were just as irrational as many supposed debunkings are these days. It would be good if the grander theoretical physics community had a better sense of the logical foundations of its subject, such as to then be able to make objective, substantive judgements. Much of the criticism of string theory is based on confusion already about QFT (such as the common "string theory doesn't work because the perturbation series does not converge" or "because it doesn't have a unique vacuum").

Comment: @Trimok String phenomenology is not practical in the sense we have not found KK states, extra dimensions,... So far. However, it is TRUE that string theory phenomenology have been "useful" for studies on modified newtonian gravity, D-brane technology (theoretical framework now doing incursions in theoretical condensed matter), or even the moonshine can be considered a "phenomenological" alternative Universe we don't live in (apparently). I am aware of the power of string theory from the mathematical viewpoint, but we are "lost in translation" without experimental evidences of it.

Comment: Feynman had at least two arguments against "string theory": 1st. Why should people roll up dimensions in certain way? 2nd. String theory has no definite answer for the issue of the origin of mass, it only shifts it to another way.  Of course, we could say all these problems are already known, but they do exist. And the cosmological constant problem is not solved "clean" with string theory in its current formulation. The theory has its merits, even critic people like me do NOT deny (I am NOT anti-strings). It is quite curious that when strong criticism arises against it, people "complain"...

Comment: Feynman criticism can be read in the book (from the BBC interviews): Superstrings, a theory of everything? So, I am not inventing data...Criticism is good to improve theories...And I am aware that, with care, SUSY or strings can give mass ratios, but the questions IS why should choose certain symmetries in the mass mixing matrices, mixing angles->ratios of mass and not others? We are blind there...We need some symmetry to rule the CKM/PMNS matrices and that symmetry is quite ad hoc in string theory, SUGRA, SUSY models... We need data and to think deeper about   what Nature is trying to tell us